# How do I access a LUUID using mongocxx?

Tags: c++, mongodb, uuid, mongo-cxx-driver

Essentially, the capped database I am working with has legacy UUID's (LUUID) as it's main way of indexing. I do not own the capped database. I'm writing code to persist some of the data, and would like to keep the unique ID's.

However, there doesn't seem to exist a getter method for these fields (LUUID), according to this documentation:
https://mongocxx.org/api/current/classbsoncxx_1_1document_1_1element.html

So my question is, after fetching a document, how do I even access the LUUID field? What getter method do I use to not get an exception?

Comment: According to [the documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/bson-types/#binary-data) "UUID (old)" is a subtype of the `b_binary` type. Does that help?